# Ansible file processing / blockinfile module in Windows

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-module

I want to udpate block of multiline text in a file in Windows via ansible. Have used [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) 
but it works only on Linux machines. Are there any alternative for this module ? Or any other way to do this? There is [win_lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_lineinfile_module.html) but I have around  20 lines to be added. 
Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no module that allows a block of lines to be written on a Windows host.

You may want to use win_shell module and Out-File cmdlet of Powershell as a workaround